# Not understanding why my program doesnt work

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am pretty new to programming and python. My question is I had these lines running but first I'll explain. I wanted to write a program that would ask your weight in pounds and my program would convert it to kgs. Now here is the correct answer:

```
weight = input ("What is your weight in pounds? ")
converter = int(weight) * 0.45
print (converter)
```

Now I wanted it to work for decimals (lbs in decimals). So I wrote this:

```
weight = input ("What is your weight in pounds? ")
converter = int(0.45) * weight
print (converter)
```

But the second program doesn't work. Can anyone explain why? Thank you

Comment: If you want the output in float just multiply `0.45 * weight`
int(0.45) = 0; so this will never work.

Comment: You still need to convert input from a string. `float(weight)` then multiply it by your conversion number. `float(weight) * .45`

Comment: Please try to select a title *specific to your individual problem*. A title that thousands of other questions could also use is not a good title.

Answer (score 2):

`int(0.45)` converts the 0.45 to an integer (whole number) which is truncated to 0 so you are effectively multiplying any input by 0.

In the original program you were taking the input as a string with the `input` command and then converting that string to an integer with `int(weight)`. If you want to have the program work with decimals then you would want to use `float(weight)`

Comment: Well I made a mistake while typing the second program, I actually wrote

weight = input ("What is your weight in pounds? ")

converter = float(0.45) * weight

print (converter)

but I understood where my mistake actually was and fixed it. Thank you so much for your reply ^_^

Answer (score 0):

In your second program you are casting to int the number 0.45 which evaluates to be 0 In order for this to work with float, just remove the int() before the 0.45 , because it's a floating number the whole expression will be float.

Answer (score 0):

weight = input ("What is your weight in pounds? ")

The above code always returns a string.

If you try running the following after the above line you will notice it prints **str**, which means its a string data type.

```
print(type(weight))
```

Now that we know the type of data store in the variable weight is of **str**, we need to ensure that we convert it into a number before using it in a mathematical equation.

In your case i understand that, in your second program you want to have your output of the variable **converter** in decimals.

hence you have to rewrite the line as follows:

```
converter = 0.45 * float(weight)
```

In order to ensure that the converter variable holds a decimal value, you can try:

```
print(type(converter))
```

if the above line gives the output as **float**, you have got your intended output.

For future reference, you may refer this link which shows all the data types available in Python: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datatypes.html